# Can we define enum inside a function?

Tags: c++, enums

We can define **class/struct** inside a function. Can we also define **enum** and **union** inside a function?

```
void fun() {
    enum {BIG, MID, SMALL};
    // other code.
}
```

I can compile the code with gcc 4.8.2, but I'm not sure if it's legal.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Yes**, it is perfectly ok to define an enum inside a function. Your code portrays perfectly legal anonymous enum declaration.

Structs and classes may be declared within a function
as well (and may also be anonymous).
The only limitation with types that are declared within
a function (rather than at namespace or class scope)
is that they cannot be used as template parameters.

`more information on` [Enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

## C++11 onwards

Well the limitation regarding template parameters has been changed since C++ 11, for more information on template parameters can be found on link [Template Parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

Comment: *Could* not be used as template parameters.

Comment: That limitation has changed since c++11: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef41907c81b5502f)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are correct, completely missed it, thanks for reminding it, editing the answer. Is there any reference mentioned in official standard, I was having trouble finding it in official C++11 standard ?