# Is Redefining an Enum Class as a Enum Within Main An Issue?

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors, scope, declaration

```
enum class Anything
{
Apple,
Banna,
Cookie
}

int main()
{
enum Anything
{
Apple,
Banna,
Cookie
}

}
```

```
enum class Anything
{
Apple,
Banna,
Cookie
}

enum Anything
{
Apple,
Banna,
Cookie
}

int main()
{

}
```

The compiler will run the top code but it will not run the bottom. I wish I could add colour to show you which one could run. If you redefine it outside of main(), it's a no-no. If you redefine it inside of main(), it's fine.

Could someone tell me if this is supposed to happen with enums?

**" Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question. If the answers there do not address your problem, please edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique. "**

No, the question is not about whether enums can be declared within a function.

04/11/21: Changed the incorrect syntax from ";" to ","

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: how you use the second one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we define enum inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766301/can-we-define-enum-inside-a-function)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I didn't want to. I just realised it could be done and it could lead to a crash.

Comment: @apple apple No. The legality of creating an enum within a function does not answer my question. My question is about whether this is safe to use. Normally, if you try to define the same thing twice, the compiler will highlight an error. However, in the examples above, there seems to be a workaround. A method to bypass the double definition error.

Answer (score 2):

For starters pay attention to that you wrote the enumerations syntactically incorrectly.

Nevertheless names declared in an inner scope hide the same names declared in the outer scope.

In the first program the name Anything declared in the outer block of the function main hides the declaration with the same name declared in the global namespace.

To access in main the declaration of the enumeration in the global namespace you could use its qualified name. Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Anything
{
    Apple, Banana, Cookie
};

int main() 
{
    enum Anything
    {
        Apple, Banana, Cookie
    };
    
    std::cout << "Banana = " << Banana << '\n';
    std::cout << "::Anything::Banana = " << static_cast<int>( ::Anything::Banana )
              << '\n';
              
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Banana = 1
::Anything::Banana = 1
```

In the second program the name Anything is redefined in the global namespace. So the compiler issues an error.

You could declare with the same name in the same scope for example a class and a function. In this case the function will hide the class. To reference the class type you will need to use its elaborated type specifier.

Comment: So, is my OP an issue? Because I think it can crash a program.

Comment: @JonhSmithBenjamin I am sorry. I have not understood the question.

Comment: Will allowing the compiler to have re-definition of an enum class with an enum within main BUT disallowing the re-defintion outside of main, be an issue?

Comment: @JonhSmithBenjamin What is the issue? Follow the rules of the language and you will not issues.

Comment: I'm unsure if there won't be problems. However, I'll just report this and let experts, like yourself, decide if it's an issue.